# Работа с выпадающим окном через selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Не могу разобраться с работой выпадающих окон через selenium python. Есть окно, при нажатии на которое выпадает панель со списком, нужно выбрать 6 строку. Пытался кликнуть на нужную строку используя поиск через xpath, но выдает ошибку, кликнуть на первоначальное окно удается и выпадает панель, а вот как дальше дойти до цели не могу сообразить. Привожу скрин дерева[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и xpath: /html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6tUm.jpg)/div/div/div/aside/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ui-scroll/div/div/div/ul/li[6]

Comment: Шестая строка последняя или есть ещё?

Comment: @JackWolf, есть еще, но шестая последняя видимая, остальное скролом выводится

Comment: есть одна идея, но она костыльная, нужно ли показывать?

Comment: @JackWolf, если не затруднит. Один вариант только что нашел, хотелось бы еще увидеть способы решения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала кликаем на форму для открытия выпадающего меню, ждем прогрузки (1 секунды хватит), а затем уже жмем в меню на нужную строку. По хорошему xpath  сократить надо, но способ работает, надеюсь кому нибудь пригодится.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/aside/div/div/div/div[2]/div/ui-counter/div/ng-transclude/input").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/aside/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ui-scroll/div/div/div/ul/li[6]/a").click()
```